# Duplicate Outputs in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm generating developer documentation using Doxygen. It's parsing all of the files correctly, but the output is generating duplicate entries in the member function list and class diagram.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Been a while since I used Doxygen. Can you post launch options, if any?

Comment: I'm using 'doxygen Spectr' to kick it off where Spectr is the name of the Doxygen file. I'm using all of the default values in the Doxygen Config file with the exception of setting Recursive = YES.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and found that I had accidentally specified a build folder in the `INPUT` line due to `RECURSIVE` being on, e.g.,

Example file structure:

```
./
  MyLibrarySources/
  Libs/
  build/
```

Doxyfile:

```
INPUT     = ./ MyLibrarySources/ ...
RECURSIVE = YES
```

This caused Doxygen to parse the headers from two different locations: once from `MyLibrarySources/`, and once from `build/`, producing duplicate members and other odd results.

The easy solution is to add your build directory to the `EXCLUDE` line, e.g.:

```
EXCLUDE   = "build"
```

This makes Doxygen not parse the same header files in two different locations. And yes, in-source build directories are usually a bad idea, place them elsewhere. In my case, command-line builds not issued from my IDE went there by default.

*Edit note:* I had incorrectly believed that the source files were being parsed twice because of the double-specification in the `INPUT` line. This is not the case. Doxygen is smart about this and will not parse the same physical file twice .

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use and on which platform as I could not reproduce the problem?

Comment: @albert Your commment prompted me to investigate further, and turns out that the real problem was the build dir not being excluded from parsing. I changed those two things in the Doxyfile at the same time while debugging, and had assumed it was the `INPUT` that solved it, not the `EXCLUDE`. Now this answer will actually help people! ;)